# difference between this.key and this[key] using angularjs forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looping over a simple object using `forEach` function, I'm passing the object as the context.

When I try to access an object property using `this[key]` it works but `this.key` doesn't work, can someone tell us why it behaves so?

```
var calendar =  {
        moveAll: false,
        moveSingleDay: false,
        translateRange : false
}

angular.forEach(calendar, function(val, key){
      console.log(this[key]); // returns val
      console.log(this.key); // returns undefined
}, calendar);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.key` is equivalent to `this['key']`.

Comment: this['key'] allow you to do ... var str = 'key' ... this[str] ... thus you can dynamically access properties

Answer (score 2):

That is because your `calendar` object has no property named `key`.

**Note:** In the expression `this.key` `key` won't be replaced by the value of variable named `key`.

Answer (score 0):

The key variable will contain the indexes of your array, for example: (1,2,3...) what you are trying to do when you type this.key is like 
this.1 that why you get undefined